# Derivative with two variables

Tags: geometry, functions, trigonometry, derivatives

Since I don't have enough reputation, the picture for the question is stored in the link below.
https://goo.gl/UaokHA

Point A and Point B are `a` km and `b` km from the canal respectively

It is known that:

$$ \frac{dL}{d\theta} = \frac{a*sin(\theta)}{cos^2(\theta)} + \frac{b*sin(\phi)}{cos^2(\phi)} \frac{d\phi}{d\theta} $$

Where $$ L = AP + PB $$

Also, it is known that $$ a*tan(\theta) + b*tan(\phi) $$ is constant.

So how can I prove that $$ \frac{d\phi}{d\theta}= \frac{-a*cos^2\phi}{b*cos^2 \theta} $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Differentiate $a\tan(\theta) + b\tan(\phi) = C$ with respect to $d\theta$.
$$\frac{d}{d\theta}(a\tan(\theta) + b\tan(\phi)) = \frac{d}{d\theta}C$$
Solve for $\frac{d\phi}{d\theta}$.